# How to override default Bourbon neat grid

Tags: html, sass, bourbon, neat

I'm trying to override the default **bourbon neat grid** but my method seems to be failing. Below is my `_grid-settings.scss` file

```
@import 'neat-helpers';

$visual-grid: true !global;
$visual-grid-color: #d5eefb !global;
$visual-grid-index: back !global;

// Change grid settings
$column: em(101);
$grid-columns: 6;
$gutter: em(20);

// Device widths
$tablet: em(768);
$desktop: em(960);

// Breakpoints
$tablet: new-breakpoint(min-width $tablet 6) ;
$desktop: new-breakpoint(min-width $desktop 6);
```

Below is my `tools-dir.scss. This gettings pulled into my main.scss file.

```
@import 'bourbon';
@import 'grid-settings';
@import 'neat';
```

What am I doing wrong. The documentation doesnt really explain how to either.

Comment: Which exactly parameter doesn't work? All of them?
Are you sure that bourbon and neat has been imported?

Comment: @fadehelix all of them and yes it is importing. The default grid appears.

Comment: What happens when you add !default at the end of $grid-colums rule ?
$grid-columns: 6 !default

Comment: @fadehelix nothing. I've added default, important... still no luck.